# Rails: ActiveModel Error when creating new record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemodel

I have one controller (patients) that passes a patient_id to another controller (referral_requests) to use in building the referral request record. I am running into the following error when trying to create the referral request. What am I doing wrong? My referral_requests table includes an integer column for user_id.

I have multiple user types defined with enums. Staff users create both patients and referral requests.

Thanks for any help!

**error:**

```
(0.1ms)  rollback transaction
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fe696696fc0 @base=#<ReferralRequest id: nil, content: nil, user_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, patient_id: 4, call_option_1: nil, call_option_2: nil, call_option_3: nil, call_option_1_status: nil, call_option_2_status: nil, call_option_3_status: nil, status: "created">, @messages={:user_id=>["can't be blank"]}, @details={:user_id=>[{:error=>:blank}]}>
```

**patients controller create action:**

```
def create
  @patient = current_user.patients.build(patient_params)
  if @patient.save
    flash[:success] = "Patient Created!"
    redirect_to new_referral_request_path(patient_id: @patient.id)
  else
    Rails.logger.info(@patient.errors.inspect)
    render 'patients/new'
end
```

**referral_requests controller new and create actions, and params:**

```
def new
  @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id]) 
  @referral_request = current_user.referral_requests.build(patient:  @patient) if signed_in?
end

def create
  @referral_request = current_user.referral_requests.build(referral_request_params)
  if @referral_request.save
        flash[:success] = "Referral Request Created!"
        redirect_to new_dispatch_path(referral_request_id:   @referral_request.id)
  else
    Rails.logger.info(@referral_request.errors.inspect)
    @feed_items = []
    render 'static_pages/home'
  end
end

private

def referral_request_params
  params.require(:referral_request).permit(:content, :user_id, :patient_id, concern_ids: [], insurance_ids: [], race_ids: [], language_ids: [], gender_ids: [])
end
```

**Here are the model relationships:**

```
require 'active_support/concern'

module StaffUser
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_many :referral_requests, foreign_key: "user_id"

class ReferralRequest < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, -> { where role: :staff }, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'user_id'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating referrals for a patient you should make it a nested resource:

```
resources :patients do
  resources: :referral_requests, shallow: true
end
```

Since creating this resource should require authentication you want to make sure to handle that in a before filter:

```
class ReferralRequestsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
end
```

If you are rolling your own authentication solution rather than using Devise, make sure you have such a method:

```
class ApplicationController
  private
  def authenticate_user!
    redirect_to new_session_path and return unless current_user
  end
end
```

When we create the resource note that we are not taking the `user_id` (provided by the session) nor the patient id (we get it from the path segment) from the form input.

```
class ReferralRequestsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_patient, only: [:new, :create, :index]

  # GET /patients/:patient_id/referral_requests/new
  def new
    @referral_request = @patient.referral_requests.new
  end

  # POST /patients/:patient_id/referral_requests
  def create
    @referral_request = @patient.referral_requests.new(referral_request_params) do |rr|
      rr.user = current_user
    end

    if @referral_request.save
      flash[:success] = "Referral Request Created!"
      redirect_to new_dispatch_path(referral_request_id:   @referral_request.id)
    else 
      Rails.logger.info(@referral_request.errors.inspect)
      @feed_items = []
      render :new
    end
  end

  private
  def set_patient
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id])
  end

  def referral_request_params
     params.require(:referral_request)
        .permit(:content, 
           concern_ids: [], 
           insurance_ids: [], 
           race_ids: [], 
           language_ids: [], 
           gender_ids: []
        )
  end
end
```

Using a before filter will here will also validate that the patient exists since `Patient.find(params[:patient_id])` will raise `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`.

A good way to handle where a record should be created with user input and other values such a user id from the session is to pass a block:

```
@referral_request = @patient.referral_requests.new(referral_request_params) do |rr|
  rr.user = current_user
end
```

Allowing the `user_id` param from the form would make it possible for a malicious user to pass any user id by just altering the input with the web inspector!

You create the proper path in the form by passing an array:

```
<%= form_for([@patient, @referral_request]) do |f| %>
```

Comment: Thanks Max - in the line with shallow: true, did you intend to use referral_requests instead of referrals? I just want to make sure there isn't some aliasing going on that I'm not understanding.

Comment: Yes exactly - it should be `resources: :referral_requests, shallow: true`.

Comment: This is very helpful - why is patient_id not included in the params?

Comment: Because its a segment of the path. You're posting to `/patients/:patient_id/referrals`

Comment: So it is part of the params - but not the form parameters.

Comment: Thanks - this was very helpful - if you have any time to help me figure out some parts of my project that I'm finding difficult, I'd greatly appreciate! No worries of course if not. Contact info in profile.

Comment: This is nice, but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @MichaelChaney thats up to the asker to decide.  It does not salvage the code in the question, not all answers do.

Comment: @max, I'm speaking factually.  He asks why he's getting an error (the actual question is a bit buried) and the reason has to do with his validations.  It's not addressed here.  This is *really* useful information and, frankly, is the kind of code review needed by the original inquisitor.  I'm just pointing out that it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @MichaelChaney read my answer again. It does address the issue which is caused by improperly passing the current user through the form paeans.

Comment: He's not passing the user through the form paeans.  He added it to the permitted params list while trying stuff out.  The problem is simply that he tried validating the presence of "user_id" instead of simply "user".  And that's the actual answer to the question.  I note that I did a crappy job of answering it so I'm going to fix that now.  I'm not digging on you - your answer here is great information for the original inquisitor.  It just doesn't answer the actual question that was asked.  If you simply add the information about the validation you can fix that :)

Answer (score 1):

"user_id" shouldn't be in your permitted parameters list.

edit:

The actual issue from the comments is that he's validating the presence of "user_id" instead of "user". When creating a record through an association the id won't be filled in until later in the process, so you just check for the presence of the associated item rather than the id:

```
validates :user, presence: true
```

Comment: I just removed and still get the same error - I think I added it hoping that would fix it.

Comment: When I add debugger before the referral request is saved in the create method of the referral requests controller, I can see that user_id is nil when I call the referral request but that current_user seems to be working as it returns the current user.

Comment: to be clear - i am enforcing a model validation for referral request that requires user_id be present. I just don't understand why it isn't getting passed through to the referral request even though current_user is evaluating just fine.

Comment: Your problem then is forcing "user_id" to be present.  You need to instead validate the presence of "user".